# How can I repair this cracked plastic caravan skylight?

Tags: repair, caravan-camper

We purchased a retro 1970s Viking fibreline caravan on Saturday and promptly pushed it into our carport. The crunching sounds alerted us to the height of the caravan and now I'm left with a skylight that has two extra shards and a missing shard...

The plastic is very brittle due to its age and has a coarse feel to it. Whilst I can probably glue the missing shards on, can anyone suggest a good, visually appealing and waterproof way of covering the gap left by the missing shard?

The most important thing is that it's watertight. We live in the UK and there's lots of rain here. Next is looks because it's a beautifully restored caravan and it would be a real shame to just use duck tape or whatever.

Also advice for the cracks where the bolts are also appreciated!

If it's not possible then I was thinking maybe find someone who can vacuum form a new one but that might be very expensive and time consuming!

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: You can buy plastic welding tips and white plastic rod. You'd have to find out what type of plastic the cover is. Once it's sanded it usually looks pretty good.

Comment: Find a tray baking or otherwise and use that to mold a plastic sheet over to re-make one using heat. Haven't tried it on such a large scale but may work- of course don't use the best baking tray!!!

Comment: Is there some kind of repair tape that you can paint epoxy on to or something like that? I think that might work?

Comment: You might want to clarify whether the translucency is important (I expect it is given this is a skylight). If it isn't you might want to give bondo or body putty a go

Comment: It is but we'd actually like it a bit darker.. in any case it lets a good amount of diffused light in like this

Comment: I'm going to call a few places today that do one off vacuum forming.. I think creating a mould and then forming plastic around it should do the trick. I'm also tempted to get a few made for other unfortunate Viking owners! Possibly..

Comment: PUT A SHEET OF FIBREGLASS OVER IT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to find the missing peice... Through sheer luck. Then I used 2 part epoxy to glue it all together. Time will tell if it'll hold but it feels solid. Good stuff Epoxy.

Comment: 3 years on it's still good :) Yay for epoxy.

Comment: So eventually we found someone that made these and bought a new one.. however the epoxy still stayed strong and lasted forever.